# Shell script to find .java or .scala file in a project from root directory of project which loop through all the dir and subdir to find files

Tags: shell, git-bash

My requirement is to find all `.java` and `.scala` files in a project having many directories and subdirectories using bash shell scripting using for loop

eg;  project(clone from git) contains folder below
`src.main.com.abhi.java`

`src.test.com.abhi.scala`

The main goal is to find all `.java` and `.scala` files and add a single line comment to it using a bash script. I have to do it in many projects therefore, need to write a bash shell script.

Comment: Where in each file would you like to add a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory containing all the files and run this one liner command:

`find \( -iname '*.scala' -o -iname '*.java' \) -exec sh -c  'echo "The comment to enter" >> {}'  \;`

Replace `The comment to enter` with the text you want to add and you will be alright.